# некорректная работа телеграм-бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Задумка: Вводишь дату, бот выводит праздник в этот день. При открытии бота должен появляться следующий текст:

> Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER

Список праздников находится в отдельном файле. Не могу понять, что не так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
    data = input()
    if message.text == data:
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(data))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

```
import telebot
import slovar

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1770077388:AAHQa8lA-Qh1VX9X1xUJm1KRoaxwFk7uia0')
data = input()


def func(message):
    if message.text == data:
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(data))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(data, func)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Эникейщик на скрине видно, что не из списка берет, а начальное выводит. И начальное сообщение появляется только если перезапустить бота, а просто выйти и войти, его нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = input()` считывает текст с командной строки, а не текст который вы вводите боту
Для того чтобы правильно всё реализовать надо использовать
`bot.register_next_step_handler` - эта функция ждёт ответ от пользователя

### Как применить в вашем случае

Вам надо немного подправить код:

```py
def func(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(data))
    except as Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")
        print(Exception)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(data, func)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

С этого выходит что `bot.register_next_step_handler` применяет 2 аргумента

1. Это сообщение на которое должен ответить юзер
2. Функция которую надо выполнить после ответа.

Comment: Скопипастил ваш код полностью. не ищет по списку. Возможно я что-то недопанимаю и не так. Можно код целикам как должно?

Comment: Хоть что-то присилает после написания дат?

Comment: @ Іван Шнір нет

Comment: Скиньте тогда весь свой код, с моими поправками. И заскриньте результат и ошибки если они есть

Comment: @ Іван Шнір в задачу добавил с вашими изменениями. ошибок не выдает

Comment: Изменил код, попробуйте этот

Comment: прошу прощения, а где он?

Comment: Скопируйте новый, и вставьте место старого кода.

Comment: я удалил data в func и теперь на ввод текста он по очереди выводит вхардкоженные фразы

Comment: Вам помогло? Если да то поставьте зелёную галочку. Именно там я и допустил ошибку

Comment: @ Іван Шнір К сожалению он не ищет в списке, а по очереди выводит про в этот день празд нет и введите дату...

Comment: @ Іван Шнір cкрин в вопросу приложил)